# Azure - How to update the password profile of a user in Azure AD B2C using the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to change the password of a user in Azure AD B2C using the update endpoint provided by the Microsoft Graph API.

I followed this Microsoft documentation when I implemented this -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request

Following is the code I used,

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string tenantId = "tenant-id";
        string clientId = "client-id";
        string clientSecret = "client-secret";
        var objectId = "object-id";
        var newPassword = "newPassword";

        try
        {
            string accessToken = await GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            await ResetPassword(accessToken, objectId, newPassword);

            Console.WriteLine("Password reset successfully!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }

    }

    static async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
            var body = $"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

            var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var tokenJson = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(responseBody).RootElement;
            string accessToken = tokenJson.GetProperty("access_token").GetString();

            return accessToken;
        }
    }

    static async Task ResetPassword(string accessToken, string objectId, string newPassword)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

            string graphApiEndpoint = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{objectId}";

            var body = new
            {
                passwordProfile = new
                {
                    forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                    password = newPassword
                }
            };

            var jsonBody = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(body);
            var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await httpClient.PatchAsync(graphApiEndpoint, content);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        }
    }
```

The access token was obtained for the tenant and using this access token the update endpoint in Graph API was called but a 403 error (Insufficient privileges to complete the operation) was returned.

I created an application for this console app in the Azure AD B2C and added the following permissions,
Directory.AccessAsUser.All (Delegated), Directory.ReadWrite.All (Application), User.ReadWrite.All (Application)

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have assigned "User Administrator" or "Global Administrator" role to the application

Navigate to Azure Portal > Azure AD > Roles and Administrators> User Administrator > Click on Add Assignments > select the application > click on Add button.

Note: This will take 10-15 minutes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

In application-only access, the calling app must have the `User.ReadWrite.All` application permission and must have at least the `User Administrator` Azure AD built-in role.

Resources:

[Azure AD built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference?toc=%2Fgraph%2Ftoc.json)

[Update user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request-body) - check comment for `passwordProfile` property

Comment: How can we do this "must have at least the User Administrator Azure AD built-in role."

Comment: @DilshanPrasad In my case I had to create a support ticket for company ID because I didn't have permissions to assign role

Comment: @user22250152 Cant we do the updating without a signed in user?

Answer (score 1):

Add a User Administrator role assignment for the App registration of the application created